# How to check file path (Internal or External) in android

Tags: android, file, file-upload

I am creating an chat application in android. When I upload the file then I can not trace from where the file comes from. I need to check whether it comes from external SD card or internal memory so I can add the file path to my database Sqlite.

Currently I am doing this with the following function :

```
 public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri
            .getAuthority());
}
```

It checks properly in Kitkat but working in Lolipop. So any thing more I can do ??

Comment: A `Uri` does not have to point to a file on a filesystem that you can access.

Comment: so how can I get the path ? Because I am storing the path so it will be helpful for opening the file.

Answer (score 0):

A `Uri` can point to *anything*:

- A local file on external storage
- A local file on internal storage for the other app
- A local file on removable storage for the other app
- A local file that is encrypted and needs to be decrypted on the fly
- A stream of bytes held in a `BLOB` column in a database
- A document that has to be generated on the fly, such as how Stack Overflow generates this page on the fly
- A piece of content that needs to be downloaded by the other app first
- and so on

Inexperienced developers have assumed that a `Uri` only points to a file. This has never been true. You will infrequently see a `Uri` with a `file` scheme starting later this year, as developers move to avoid [the ban on the `file` scheme](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html). And nobody with common sense will attempt to derive a filesystem path based on an inspection of the `Uri`, as there is no assurance that such a plan will work even in limited cases over time, and it will not handle the *vast* array of content sources that the user might choose from.

A `Uri` obtained via `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` might support persistable `Uri` permissions. If so, you can call `takePersistableUriPermission()` and save the `Uri` itself to your database. You will still need to deal with the case that the content is no longer available (e.g., the user deleted it).

In all other cases, only use the `Uri` for the duration of your process. If you need access to the content for longer than that, make a copy of that content into a file that you control (e.g., on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html)).